# Using Firebase as a backend for recurring tasks

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a project that, currently, is 100% Firebase. Ideally, given I'm fully Firebase, I'd like to stay with Firebase for a next task which is updating some of the records based on external API calls once per day.

I'm currently using Firebase Functions for triggered events, not using it for API calls, everything that happens in the functions is after a user does something, and doesn't respond back to any clients (only responds back to the database for updates).

Is Firestore Cloud Functions a good place to run something like this that could call an external API and then update as necessary? I saw the scheduled functions that require the Blaze plan, have considered it but not sure if there's another approach that's better built for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions that trigger on Firestore events probably aren't what you're looking for.  Firestore triggers only fire when something in your Cloud Firestore database has changed.  That means you need something that's writing to some document in the database in order to get the code to run.  Which means you need a way to schedule that operation.

No matter what kind of trigger you write, you will need to be on a billing plan in order to make external requests anyway.  So even if you somehow managed to put together a solution that uses Firestore triggers, your project would still need to be on a billing plan.

Comment: I'm currently on the Flame plan which works so far, seems switching to Blaze is my best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This approach is perfectly okay - in fact, I am using the exact same approach in my project which has 100% Firebase back-end. The overall (Firebase) Cloud Functions gives flexibility in terms of invocation i.e. they can be invoked based on trigger (e.g. storage or database event) or can be called with the HTTP end-point. So, depending on your need you can either use Firestore trigger or database trigger or call an end-point.

Switching to Blaze plan is perfectly fine since otherwise we can't call an external end-point. I switched to Blaze plan just a few months back and didn't pay anything for that as my usage is within the free limit.